# I need to make scale animation for recyclerview items?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I can't make a `scale animation` in `recyclerview` items like that image below, could you help me

```
 holder.mPhotoIv.animate().scaleX(0f)
 holder.mPhotoIv.animate().scaleY(1.2f)
```

I tried that but didn't help

Comment: there is no image below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
holder.mPhotoIv.animate().scaleX(0.0f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(1500).start();
```